# Hbase, Region Servers, Storefile Size, Indexes

Tags: hadoop, indexing, compression, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

Do you use compression with your indexes tables in Hbase? 
If so, what type of compression do you use?

I have noticed that the size of my indexes tables are every big, and grow each day... After adding new storage, the size is even bigger.

I have e.g table A with the size of **108.3 G**

In /apps/hbase/data/data/default, Index table with size of **380.0 G**,

and in /apps/hbase/data/archive/data/default, Indexe table with size of **1.2 T**

Could you advice me what to do with the size of index tables?

Why the data in archive on HDFS is so big?
/apps/hbase/data/archive/data/default

Could the size of archive catalog on HDFS be managed in some way?
Archive takes more that 2/3 of my HDFS space.

I have notice also, that I have on three tables more than a hundred 'split regions', other tables do not have 'split regions'. Do you know what could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found on stage environment, that the reason of large data in /apps/hbase/data/archive/ are caused by daily hbase snapshots that are running from cron.

So, now I will rewrite the script, and keep only one or two table snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I used snappy like this...

```
 create 't1', { NAME => 'cf1', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY' }
```

#### [Compression support Check](http://Use%20CompressionTest%20to%20verify%20snappy%20support%20is%20enabled%20and%20the%20libs%20can%20be%20loaded%20ON%20ALL%20NODES%20of%20your%20cluster:%20%20$%20hbase%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest%20hdfs://host/path/to/hbase%20snappy)

[Use `CompressionTest` to verify snappy support is enabled and the libs can be loaded ON ALL NODES of your cluster:](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/snappy.compression.html)

```
$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest hdfs://host/path/to/hbase snappy
```

For most of your questions above.. compression would help. Also look at [my answer. how it helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791227/647053)

> I have notice also, that I have on three tables more than a hundred
>   'split regions', other tables do not have 'split regions'. Do you know
>   what could be the reason?

- Make sure that pre-split the table between finite number for example 0-9.
- run compaction over table regions.

Comment: Thanks, I will add the snappy compression to index tables. I just wanted to know if it is common practise in large environments with index tables.